# mochapack Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, mocha.js, mocha-webpack

I would like to create a vuejs unit test for components.
I follow this official tutorial vuejs : [Vuejs component unit test](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-single-file-components-with-mocha-webpack.html)

I have created those file :

**setup.js (main script for all test) :**

```
require('jsdom-global')()

global.expect = require('expect')

// import jsdomGlobal from 'jsdom-global'
// export const jsdonGlobal = require('jsdom-global')
```

**home.spec.js (unit test component file) :**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Home from '../../src/page/Home.vue'
// import Home from '@/components/Home'

describe('Home.vue', () => {
  it('test the test', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Home)
    let divContainer = wrapper.find('div.container')
    expect(divContainer.children()).to.have.length(12)
  })
})
```

**my babel.config.js :**

```
module.exports = {
presets: [
    '@vue/app',
    '@babel/preset-env'
],
```

}

**and this my 'npm run test' command :**

```
 "mochapack --webpack-config webpack.config.js --require test/setup.js test/**/*.spec.js"
```

All of this generate a 'Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#' error

others informations :

- if a comment all line into setup.js and Home.spec.js file the behavior is identic (very strange behavior which difficult to understand where is the error)
- I already try this preset Babel ('@babel/preset-env') for transpiling
- I don't have a export instruction into my setup.js file and Home.spec.js file

Can you help me to understand why I have to error and how I can resolve this ?

*The all others questions don't help me to resolve this because I don't have export instruction into my test code...*

Comment: I think this will solve your problem 
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039#issuecomment-273804003

Comment: I don't have export instructions in my code and if a comment all my code the error appear again. I don't understand and this link does not help me to more understand.